# How to efficiently delete subset in spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, subset, rdd

When conducting research, I find it somewhat difficult to delete all the subsets in Spark RDD.

The data structure is `RDD[(key,set)]`. For example, it could be:

`RDD[ ("peter",Set(1,2,3)), ("mike",Set(1,3)), ("jack",Set(5)) ]`

Since the set of mike `(Set(1,3))` is a subset of peter's `(Set(1,2,3))`, I want to delete "mike", which will end up with

`RDD[ ("peter",Set(1,2,3)), ("jack",Set(5)) ]`

It is easy to implement in python locally with two "for" loop operation. But when I want to extend to cloud with scala and spark, it is not that easy to find a good solution.

Thanks

Comment: What do you do with ties? `("peter",Set(1,2,3))` & `("olga",Set(1,2,3))`

Comment: Just delete one of them. Keeping which one does not matter.

Comment: The solution provided keeps both. You are invited to adapt it to your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution. However, when applying to my case, I find some concerns. In fact, my set data structure are much bigger and more complex than `Set(1,2,3)` , and I have nearly 300000 `(key, set)`, which is about 1G. If I do it in cartesian, I doubt whether my computer will give me an answer because of the limit of memory.

Comment: The full cartesian product won't be materialized. In Spark all transformations are lazy, meaning that the cartesian, filter and map operations become one stage.If you're running on 1 computer, iterating over the collection in a double loop will be a much more space-efficient alternative. PS: use @<name> to ping somebody in a comment.

Comment: @maasg Actually I have tried it with 300K records in python locally after posting this question. After 8 hours, it was stuck and gave me barely nothing. However, it can run on a smaller dataset with 5K records. lol.

Comment: I'd be curious to know if the spark version works better than the python  loop on your dataset. Ping me on twitter @maasg if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt we can escape to comparing each element to each other (the equivalent of a double loop in a non-distributed algorithm). The subset operation between sets is not reflexive, meaning that we need to compare `is "alice" subsetof "bob"` and `is "bob" subsetof "alice"`.

To do this using the Spark API, we can resort to multiplying the data with itself using a cartesian product and verifying each entry of the resulting matrix:

```
val data = Seq(("peter",Set(1,2,3)), ("mike",Set(1,3)), ("anne", Set(7)),("jack",Set(5,4,1)), ("lizza", Set(5,1)), ("bart", Set(5,4)), ("maggie", Set(5)))
// expected result from this dataset = peter, olga,  anne, jack
val userSet = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val prod = userSet.cartesian(userSet)
val subsetMembers = prod.collect{case ((name1, set1), (name2,set2)) if  (name1 != name2) && (set2.subsetOf(set1)) && (set1 -- set2).nonEmpty => (name2, set2) }
val superset = userSet.subtract(subsetMembers)    

// lets see the results:
superset.collect()
// Array[(String, scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int])] = Array((olga,Set(1, 2, 3)), (peter,Set(1, 2, 3)), (anne,Set(7)), (jack,Set(5, 4, 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using `RDD.fold` function.
In this case the output required is a "List" (ItemList) of *superset* items. For this the input should also be converted to  "List" (RDD of ItemList)

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

// type alias for convinience
type Item = Tuple2[String, Set[Int]]
type ItemList = List[Item]

// Source RDD
val lst:RDD[Item] = sc.parallelize( List( ("peter",Set(1,2,3)), ("mike",Set(1,3)), ("jack",Set(5)) ) )


// Convert each element as a List. This is needed for using fold function on RDD
// since the data-type of the parameters are the same as output parameter 
// data-type for fold function
val listOflst:RDD[ItemList] = lst.map(x => List(x))

// for each element in second ItemList
// - Check if it is not subset of any element in first ItemList and add first
// - Remove the subset of newly added elements
def combiner(first:ItemList, second:ItemList) : ItemList = {
    def helper(lst: ItemList, i:Item) : ItemList = {
        val isSubset: Boolean = lst.exists( x=> i._2.subsetOf(x._2))
        if( isSubset) lst else i :: lst.filterNot( x => x._2.subsetOf(i._2))
    }
    second.foldLeft(first)(helper)
}


listOflst.fold(List())(combiner)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use filter after a map.

You can build like a map that will return a value for what you want to delete. First build a function:

```
def filter_mike(line):
    if line[1] != Set(1,3):
        return line
    else:
        return None
```

Then you can filter now like this:

```
your_rdd.map(filter_mike).filter(lambda x: x != None)
```

This will work

Comment: Read the question again.